# Opening File in Ruby returning empty file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

I am currently trying to store a pdf in a hash for an api call in ruby. The path to the pdf is stored as:

```
/Users/myUserName/Desktop/REPOSITORY/path_to_file.pdf
```

I am using a block to store the file in the hash as so:

```
File.open(pdf_location, "rb") do |file|
        params = {
          other irrelevant entries
          :document => file
        }
        pdf_upload_request('post', params, headers)
end
```

I am receiving a 400 error from the server that my document is empty and when I do `puts file.read`, it is empty. However, when I visit the filepath, it's clear that the file is not empty. Am I missing something here? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Edit------

I recorded my http request with vcr, here it is:

```
request:
    method: post
    uri: request_uri
    body:
      encoding: US-ASCII
      string: ''
    headers:
      Authorization:
      - Bearer 3ZOCPnwfoN7VfdGh7k4lrBuEYs4gN1
      Content-Type:
      - multipart/form-data; boundary=-----------RubyMultipartPost
      Content-Length:
      - '246659'
```

So i don't think the issue is with me sending the file with multipart encoding

Update--------

The filepaths to the pdf are generated from a url, and stored in a the tmp folder of my application. They are generated through this method:

```
def get_temporary_pdf(chrono_detail, recording, host)
    auth_token = User.find(chrono_detail.user_id).authentication_token
      # pdf_location = "https://54.84.224.252/recording/5/analysis.pdf/?token=Ybp37kw7HrSt8NyyPnBZ"
    pdf_location = host + '/recordings/' + recording.id.to_s + '/analysis.pdf/?format=pdf&download=true&token=' + auth_token
    filename = "Will" + '_' + recording.id.to_s + '_' + Date.new.to_s + '.pdf'
    Thread.new do
      File.open(Rails.root.join("tmp",filename), "wb") do |file|
        file.write(open(pdf_location, {ssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE}).read)
      end
    end
    Rails.root.join("tmp",filename)
  end
```

They are then called using the api call:

```
client.upload_document(patient_id, file_path, description)
```

I can see them physically in my temp folder, and can view them with preview. Everything seems to work. But as a test of uncertainty, I changed file_path to point to a different pdf:

```
Users/myUsername/Desktop/example.pdf.
```

Using this file path worked. The pdf was uploaded to the third party system correctly, I can physically see it there. Do you think this means it is an issue with the tmp folder or how i generate the temporary pdf's?

Comment: You probably want to use `:document => file.read`, but it really depends on what `pdf_upload_request` does. Can you post the definition of that function?

Comment: pdf_upload_request sends a post request to an api endpoint with params as the body of the request. The :document element of params must be a file, so I'm not sure if file.read is the correct format for the request. I tried it and received a 400 error:  "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the API is expecting a POST with `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`. Just sending the file handle (which `document: file` does) won't work, as the file handle is only relevant to your local Ruby process; and even sending the binary string as a parameter won't work, since your content-type isn't properly set to encode a file.

Since you're already using HTTParty, though, you can fix this by using [HTTMultiParty](https://github.com/jwagener/httmultiparty):

```
require 'httmultiparty'
class SomeClient
  include HTTMultiParty
  base_uri 'http://localhost:3000'
end

SomeClient.post('/', :query => {
  :foo      => 'bar',
  :somefile => File.new('README.md')
})
```

Comment: I am using HTTMultiParty to handle the post request to the server. This is my post request => HTTMultiParty.post(url, :body => params, :headers => headers)

Comment: Try following the example more closely and see if that helps. E.g., `HTTMultiParty.post(url, query: { document: File.new(pdf_location) })` -- the differences being "query" instead of "body", and File.new instead of File.open.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
file = File.read(pdf_location)
params = {
  # other irrelevant entries
  document: file
}
headers = {}
pdf_upload_request('post', params, headers)
```

Not sure but may be you need to close file first...

Comment: I receive the following HTTP response: <HTTParty::Response:0x7fd0ea924b78 parsed_response={"document"=>["The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."]}, @response=#<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 BAD REQUEST readbody=true>, @headers={"server"=>["nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)"], "date"=>["Wed, 29 Jul 2015 18:38:29 GMT"], "content-type"=>["application/json"], "transfer-encoding"=>["chunked"], "connection"=>["close"], "x-xss-protection"=>["1"], "x-content-options"=>["nosniff"], "strict-transport-security"=>["max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains"],

Comment: @WilliamSumfest, that means, that you are not using API correctly.

Comment: @WilliamSumfest, as answered previously you should use `httmultiparty` gem

Answer (score 0):

So the issue arose from the multi threading i used to avoid timeout errors. The file path would get generated and referenced in the api call before anything was actually written into the document.